# Is there a suggested file structure for testcafe E2E tests

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, code-organization, testcafe

Right now all my tests live in a `happy.js` file.  Now that I'm starting to write end to end tests for non happy path functionality I'm realizing I need to organize these tests better.

How would you recommend organizing the e2e files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no universal approach for organizing test structure. It strongly depends on the complexity of your project. For example, you can see how tests are organized in the [TestCafe repository](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/tree/master/test/functional)

In addition, I recommend you refer to the [Using Page Model](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/using-page-model.html) article to see how to create an abstraction of a tested page and use it in test code to refer to page elements.